# Gmail API Parse Email Thread in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using the gmail api and I can successfully use `users.messages.get` but when I parse the email body using `response.data.payload.parts[0].body.data` I get the whole thread instead of each message individually in an array. 1) Is there a function I can call to get the messages in an array or 2) Will I have to manually parse the entire thread? I'm thinking an edge case would be if a line starts with `>`. Example of how `console.log(response.data.payload.parts[0].body.data)` looks below...

```
Hello World 1

On Fri, Dec 22, 2023 at 10:52 PM Charles Simms <randomemail@gmail.com> wrote:

> Hello World 2
>
> On Fri, Dec 22, 2023 at 3:55 PM Charles Simms <randomemail@gmail.com> wrote:
>
```

I would prefer something like this `[Hello World 1, Hello World 2]`